# Meaning of "Her talent might have lain dormant had it not been for her aunt's encouragement"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

I found this sentence in usage sentences of idiom "*lie dormant*". What is its meaning? Can anyone explain?

> Her talent might have lain dormant had it not been for her aunt's
> encouragement.

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dormant)

Comment: This is a metaphorical use of *dormant*, which etymologically and literally means "sleeping". The dictionary you link defines the metaphorical meaning--what do you not understand?

Comment: I don't understand the literal MEANING of sentence.

Comment: One common use of "dormant" is in describing a volcano. A volcano that stops being dormant erupts!  Just like a dormant volcano, her talents were quiet, and might have stayed that way...but her Aunt encouraged her, and so she erupted (metaphorically) into a spectacular display of talent.

Comment: Its literal meaning is that her talent would remained sleeping--that is, would never have become evident in her life.